# Как перенести данные из excel в sql?

Tags: excel, sql

Как перенести данные из excel в sql?

Answer (score 3):

Открыть файл `Excel` с использованием [`OleDbConnection`](http://vb.net-informations.com/excel-2007/vb.net_excel_oledb.htm) или надстройки над `Office` и скопировать в БД `Sql Server` с помощью [`SqlBulkCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

В SQL Server есть мастер Import Data...

Answer (score 1):

Быстрый и грязный способ: из Excel в таблицу SQL Server можно скопипастить кусок данных при условии совпадения типов полей и их количества. Была только какая-то хитрость, AFAIR, в Excel-е нужен вначале таблицы пустой столбец.

Но аккуратнее и надежнее сделать так, как сказал [@msi](/users/2339/msi).

Comment: извиняюсь за неполноту вопроса.... дело в том, что необходимо, чтобы данные из excel-таблицы переносились в таблицу sql конечным пользователем по нажатию кнопки на web-странице (код написан на asp.net.) 
но спасибо Вам за ответ.

Comment: Тогда вам стоит обновить текст вопроса и добавить эти подробности, чтобы отвечащиюм было проще.

Comment: Опять таки не известна какая СУБД.
Посмотрите в сторону Bulk Insert.